# How to wait for result of service get?

Tags: jasmine

I'm pretty sure the *get* function of the *person* service I use below returns a function, but my test doesn't seem to execute either branch, so it times out. Does that mean that *get* does not return a promise?

```
describe('person service', function () {
  beforeEach(module('tournament'));

  var person;

  beforeEach(inject(function (_personService_) {
    person = _personService_;
  }));

  it('should get person data', (done) => {
    var expectedPerson = [
      { id: 2, last: 'Steigerwald', first: 'Michael' },
    ];

    person.get(2).then( 
      (result) => {
        expect(result).toEqual(expectedPerson);
        done();
      },
      (reason) => {
        console.log(reason.message);
        done();
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, `person.get(2)` is not returning a promise and that's why the tests are timing out.

Comment: Can you check if the `person.get()` is a promise or not?

Comment: According to Chrome Dev Tools, the result from person.get() is indeed a promise.